# swipe gesture strike through text

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I have been trying to come out a solution for using swipe gesture to the right and makes the text on a label.text with strike through effect, swipe again to remove the strike through and leaves the original text intact. Any example of codes as to how to do this? This is a XCode question.

```
if ([***this is the part i need help with***])
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self.EditItem valueForKey:@"eventName"]];
    [attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                            value:@1
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];
    self.nameTextField.attributedText = attributeString;
    [self.EditItem setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Completed"] forKey:@"eventName"];
    NSLog(@"Swiped to the right");
}
else
{
    [NSString initWithString:[self.EditItem valueForKey:@"eventName"]];
    NSLog(@"normal text no strike through");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't sound very hard. What's the part you're having trouble with?

Comment: i was using an "if" statement, maybe something else better for it.

Comment: Can you add your code so far? it will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could try a simple gesture recogniser like this..**

Add the following in your viewDidLoad or similar

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(strikeThrough)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

[self.nameTextField addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

Then setup the `strikeThrough` method to change the text to strikethrough - if you only have one textfield just add a toggle so that you can turn the strikethrough on and off.

```
bool stricken;

- (void) strikeThrough {

    if (stricken) {

        self.nameTextField.text = self.nameTextField.text;

        stricken = false;

    } else {

        NSDictionary* attributes = @{ NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] };
        NSAttributedString* attrText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.nameTextField.text attributes:attributes];
        self.nameTextField.attributedText = attrText;

        stricken = true;

  }

}
```

Comment: Your code adds strike through on text for the first swipe, swipe again does not return the text to original state.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include that.